# Javascript: call variable in a method

Tags: javascript, function, vis.js

I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for days.
In short: I would like to call "**let timeline**" externally to the method / object, I need later its properties which must therefore be global, but to read the "**fetureData**" it must remain inside the object/method.
How could I do ?

```
                        layer: {

                          onEachFeature: function(featureData){

                                          let trackItems = new attak(featureData);
                                          console.log(trackItems);

                                          let items = new vis.DataSet(trackItems);
                                          console.log(items);

                                          let timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, timelineOptions); //

                                       }
                                     },

                                     ...........
```

then it must in particular satisfy:

```
timeline.on('timechange', onCustomTimeChange);
```

and more!

Comment: Have you tried to declare `timeline` outside the `layer` object and then just assign the value to it like this: `timeline = new vis.Timeline(...)` ?

Comment: Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I need its properties inside :(

Comment: I tried them all, but one is the consequence of the other, even if I use `timeline` externally with `this.items`, the values ​​of `featureData` which corresponds to time properties are not stored in `items`